# Update cell when selected

Tags: excel, vba

I need the active cell to have automatically the actual year as soon as a cell in the range A2:A20 is selected.  My VBA code changes all the cells at once.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim i As Integer
For i = 2 To 20
    If ActiveCell = Cells(i, "A") And Cells(i, "A") = "" Then
      Cells(i, "A").Value = Year(Now)
    End If
Next i
Range("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: Make your if condition to `If ActiveCell = Cells("A", i) And Cells("A", i) = "" Then`. Fingers Crossed.

Comment: Do you only want the date to update **only** if cells A2:A20 are changed? Or do you want this to fire if those cells are *only selected* as well? Also, what is the criteria that will trigger the date to be changed. I mean what cells being changed requires cells A2:A20 to be set to the current year?

Comment: Thanks Ankit Bajpai but I have error  (TYPE MISMATCH)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman yes i want each time when the cell Ai:A20 is selected or active to automatically have the current year, but the problem with my code I do have the current year but it does automatlically to all cells (Ai:A20) at once.

Comment: @nater303 - see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want that A2:A20 to have the current year, automatically when the cell is selected, you need to use the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event. Then, in that event, you simply test if the cell that was selected is within the A2:A20 range and set the value to the current year if it is.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Me.Range("A2:A20"),Target) Is Nothing Then
     Target.Value = Year(Now())
End If

Range("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```